# Auth expires on long node process with Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am running a node process in the Google Cloud Platform that takes over an hour and continually fails as the auth token expires.

**Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.**

How can I extend the authentication timeout so that the process completes in the Google Cloud Platform?

Similar question here but I do not know how to implement the solution:
[Firebase auth expires after 1 hr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58167503/firebase-auth-expires-after-1-hr)

Edit1:
I had thought that refresh tokens may be the solution here however have just read that OAuth 2.0 refresh tokens cannot be used with Cloud Firestore.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/?hl=no#use-oauth-2-0-refresh-token

Comment: Actually Firestore accept the use of Firebase Authentication ID token [1].  Just consider the following scenarios:

- Requests come from applications
- Cloud Firestore uses Cloud Identity and Access, in order to determine if a request is authorized.

[1]https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authentication_and_authorization

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that could be useful for you is catch the error and reconnect calling the Firebase object again:

```
const {Firestore} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

// Create a new client
const firestore = new Firestore();

try {
  //my program with the error...
}
catch (e) {

   //request a new client:
   const firestore = new Firestore();
   //keep going...
}
```